# How to set duration video when streaming in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: html, asp.net-core, video-streaming, html5-video

I have a problem when streaming video in ASP.NET Core

My video have an duration time: 1:04
When I streaming this video, I want showing to user 26 seconds (40% - lenght of video)

```
using (var fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite, 65536, FileOptions.Asynchronous | FileOptions.SequentialScan))
            {
                int totalSize = (int)(fileStream.Length*0.4);
                //here we are saying read bytes from file as long as total size of file 

                //is greater then 0
                while (totalSize > 0)
                {
                    int count = totalSize > bufferSize ? bufferSize : totalSize;
                    //here we are reading the buffer from orginal file  
                    int sizeOfReadedBuffer = fileStream.Read(buffer, 0, count);
                    //here we are writing the readed buffer to output//  
                    await outputStream.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, sizeOfReadedBuffer);
                    //and finally after writing to output stream decrementing it to total size of file.  
                    totalSize -= sizeOfReadedBuffer;
                }
                //outputStream.Position = 0;
            }
```

outputstream return the stream by Response.Body

```
var stream = context.HttpContext.Response.Body;
```

But when response to html video tag, it's always show duration time 1:04. I want to set duration time of this video by 26 seconds (40%)

Please help me!!!

Answer (score 2):

Use this solution instead, this will stream 40% of your video/audio:

**API Controller** :

```
[ApiController]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class StreamerController : ControllerBase
{
    const string Filename = @"C:\PathToYourAudio\Stream.mp3";

    [HttpGet("Stream")]
    public IActionResult Stream()
    {
        byte[] fileData;

        using (FileStream fs = System.IO.File.OpenRead(Filename))
        {
            using (BinaryReader binaryReader = new BinaryReader(fs))
            {
                fileData = binaryReader.ReadBytes((int)(fs.Length * 0.4));
            }
        }

        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(fileData);
        return new FileStreamResult(stream, new MediaTypeHeaderValue("audio/mpeg").MediaType);
    }
}
```

**View** :

```
<audio controls="controls" autoplay="autoplay">
    <source src="/api/Streamer/Stream" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```

[Sample Code](https://github.com/MoienTajik/AspNetCoreStreamTest)

Comment: I try this way before by using MemoryStream, but I have same result.
because I need set duration of video to 0:26 (40% of 1:04) and right now, it's always show 1:04 at end of progress bar

Comment: @user3836200 I got the same result you want with that code while I was answering, could you retry with exactly code I sent above ?

Comment: Yes, I'll try your code above but not change the result. Here result https://uphinhnhanh.com/images/2018/12/23/Screen-Shot-2018-12-23-at-12.54.29-PM.png always on display 1:04 :(

Comment: @user3836200 ok, I added sample code to the original answer ;)

Comment: my project is working well (streaming video/audio) but I want to set the duration time  exactly with 40% of lenght. But in my project and your sample, it'll showing duration of the original file :( example: the original file: 1:04, 40%: 26 seconds, when streaming, progress bar is paused 40%, it's working fine, but the duration is 1:04 ^^! I want to set this value is 0:26, but I can't find the way to slove :(

Comment: @user3836200 Here is my result, Original audio duration is 2:043 seconds, but with the above code, I just streamed 40% of that which is 1:04. Remove your browser history or try with another browser to see the result. https://imgur.com/a/nnUFZjB

Comment: I'm sorry and you right. that's my fault, after I try another browser it's working fine with audio resource. but.... when I try video file, nothing change, in the progress bar still showing original video duration. You can try another video file? I tried by memoryStream and Stream by httpResponse. Sorry, my English is not good!